# Connect to kubernetes engine from app engine standard

Tags: google-app-engine, kubernetes, google-compute-engine, google-kubernetes-engine

We want to access some services on Google Kubernetes Engine from a Google App Engine standard via http(s). We don't want to expose the services to external networks because of security.

- app engine flexible can use private network with an [internal loadbalancer](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/internal-load-balancing?hl=ja) or [vpc](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/vpc/?hl=ja)([post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51198865/connect-to-kubernetes-engine-from-app-engine)). How about app engine standard?
- 2 years ago, we could not do it. ([post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34747449/connect-from-appengine-to-a-kubernetes-service-from-google-containers))
- We can set rules about IP addresses, but an IP address for an app engine standard is not static.

What is the best solution?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

> app engine flexible can use private network with an internal loadbalancer or vpc(post). How about app engine standard?

Not really as per [this](https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/vpc):

"A VPC network, sometimes just called a “network,” is a virtual version of a physical network, like a data center network. It provides connectivity for your Compute Engine virtual machine (VM) instances, Kubernetes Engine clusters, App Engine Flex instances, and other resources in your project."

> We can set rules about IP addresses, but an IP address for an app engine standard is not static.

Yes. They are always changing. The recommendation here is to their [Static IP range](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/kb/) combined with:

> Instead, we suggest that you take a [defense in depth](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Defense_in_depth_(computing)) approach using [OAuth](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OAuth) and [Certs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Public_key_certificate).

You could also look at things like [Cloud Armor](https://cloud.google.com/armor/) (in alpha as of this writing), or a [Virtual WAF](https://console.cloud.google.com/marketplace/details/brocade-public-1063/safpx-csub-1000). Longer term it would make more sense to move your workloads from Google App engine into GKE.

Comment: Thank you so much.